# How to rename all the key in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a documents like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5705fe62d0d50b2316617508"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-04-07T11:12:43.917Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5705fe62d0d50b2316617508"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-04-07T11:12:43.917Z"),
    "XString" : "bb"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5705fe62d0d50b2316617508"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-04-07T11:12:43.917Z"),
    "XString" : "ba"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5705fe62d0d50b2316617508"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-04-07T11:12:43.917Z"),
    "XString" : "dd"
}
```

how i can update key "XString" to "Name" and if the XString is not there it should add "Name"

tried by using $rename as:

```
db.articles.update({}, {$set:{$rename: {'XString':'Name'}}},{upsert:true});
```

but it gives error as:

```
The dollar ($) prefixed field '$rename' in '$rename' is not valid for storage.
```

Tried other way:

```
db.articles.update({}, {$rename: {'XString': 'Name'}}, false, true);
but its not adding the key is it does not exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MongoDB server version is 3.2 you can use the [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) method.  Of course you need to use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) as already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36477290/3100115). Also the `updateMany()` method doesn't take the "multi" option.

*Last but not least major drivers deprecate the `update()` method since version 3.0*

The following query rename "XString" to "Name" where "XString" exists.

```js
db.articles.updateMany(
    { "XString": { "$exists": true } },
    { "$rename": { "XString": "Name" } }
)
```

To set default value where the "XString" doesn't exist, use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator.

```js
db.articles.updateMany(
    { "Name": { "$exists": false } },
    { "$set": { "Name": "" } }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrong option. You want `"multi"` and not `"upsert"`:

```js
db.articles.update(
  { "XString": { "$exists": true } },
  { "$rename": { 'XString': 'Name' } },
  { "multi": true }
);
```

The [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) test makes sure you are only selecting documents where the key you are renaming is actually there.

Also [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) is a "update modifier" which means it is a "top level" argument of the "update" document.

The `"multi"` means to affect **all** matched documents, rather than just the "first".

If you want a "blank" value where the key does not actually exist then you do the opposite, and preferably after the `$rename` operation:

```js
db.articles.update(
  { "Name": { "$exists": false } },
  { "$set": { 'Name': '' } },
  { "multi": true }
);
```

Comment: it worked same as : db.articles.update({}, {$rename: {'XString': 'Name'}}, false, true);
need to add Name key if its not there...is that possible ?

Comment: @HarjeetJadeja You need the `$exists` in the query portion